# How to delete Batch Process Logs in Salesforce?

Tags: logging, asyncapexjob

Was running some tests in my dev org and got this:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, storage limit exceeded: []

I know the issue is due to logs getting cluttered with info on batch jobs. I went to `Setup > Data Management`and saw that 97% of my allotted 5MB was taken up by Batch Process Log entries.

I've been trying to look for a way to remove them. I tried doing a delete on all entries of the ApexLog but the problem persists.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194045&language=en_US&type=1) link?

Comment: I did not think that logs counted against storage space. Is Batch Process Logs a custom object perhaps

Comment: @Eric Doh! It is a custom object. That's the problem when you're just a spec in a macrocosm. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Shiva - Added as answer so we can close it out. Been there many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not think that logs counted against storage space. Is Batch Process Logs a custom object perhaps –

Try deleting those records